# How to 'flatten' lines from text file if they meet certain criteria using Python?

Tags: python, api

To start I am a complete new comer to Python and programming anything other than web languages.

So, I have developed a script using Python as an interface between a piece of Software called Spendmap and an online app called Freeagent. This script works perfectly. It imports and parses the text file and pushes it through the API to the web app.

What I am struggling with is Spendmap exports multiple lines per order where as Freeagent wants One line per order. So I need to add the cost values from any orders spread across multiple lines and then 'flatten' the lines into One so it can be sent through the API. The 'key' field is the 'PO' field. So if the script sees any matching PO numbers, I want it to flatten them as per above.

This is a 'dummy' example of the text file produced by Spendmap:

> 5090071648,2013-06-05,2013-09-05,**P000001**,1133997,***223.010***,20,2013-09-10,104,xxxxxx,AP
> COMMENT,002091
>
> 301067,2013-09-06,2013-09-11,**P000002**,1133919,***42.000***,20,2013-10-31,103,xxxxxx,AP
> COMMENT,002143
>
> 301067,2013-09-06,2013-09-11,**P000002**,1133919,***359.400***,20,2013-10-31,103,xxxxxx,AP
> COMMENT,002143
>
> 301067,2013-09-06,2013-09-11,**P000003**,1133910,***23.690***,20,2013-10-31,103,xxxxxx,AP
> COMMENT,002143

The above has been formatted for easier reading and normally is just one line after the next with no text formatting.

The 'key' or PO field is the first bold item and the second bold/italic item is the cost to be totalled. So if this example was to be passed through the script id expect the first row to be left alone, the Second and Third row costs to be added as they're both from the same PO number and the Fourth line to left alone.

**Expected result:**

> 5090071648,2013-06-05,2013-09-05,**P000001**,1133997,***223.010***,20,2013-09-10,104,xxxxxx,AP
> COMMENT,002091
>
> 301067,2013-09-06,2013-09-11,**P000002**,1133919,***401.400***,20,2013-10-31,103,xxxxxx,AP
> COMMENT,002143
>
> 301067,2013-09-06,2013-09-11,**P000003**,1133910,***23.690***,20,2013-10-31,103,xxxxxx,AP
> COMMENT,002143

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated and if you need any further details just say.

Thanks in advance for looking!

Comment: "The above has been formatted for easier reading": don't do this.  That introduces a new problem, where it's hard to tell what you've changed.  E.g. are the comments always on the line after the data, or are they on the same line and you just forgot a trailing comma?

Comment: Apologies, i'll know for next time. Was just trying to ensure I was explaining as clearly as possible. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a dictionary to compile the lines, using `get(key,0.0)` to sum values if they exist already, or start with zero if not:

```
InputData = """5090071648,2013-06-05,2013-09-05,P000001,1133997,223.010,20,2013-09-10,104,xxxxxx,AP COMMENT,002091
301067,2013-09-06,2013-09-11,P000002,1133919,42.000,20,2013-10-31,103,xxxxxx,AP COMMENT,002143
301067,2013-09-06,2013-09-11,P000002,1133919,359.400,20,2013-10-31,103,xxxxxx,AP COMMENT,002143
301067,2013-09-06,2013-09-11,P000003,1133910,23.690,20,2013-10-31,103,xxxxxx,AP COMMENT,002143"""

OutD = {}
ValueD = {}

for Line in InputData.split('\n'):
    # commas in comments won't matter because we are joining after anyway
    Fields = Line.split(',') 
    PO = Fields[3]
    Value = float(Fields[5])
    # set up the output string with a placeholder for .format()
    OutD[PO] = ",".join(Fields[:5] + ["{0:.3f}"] + Fields[6:])
    # add the value to the old value or to zero if it is not found
    ValueD[PO] = ValueD.get(PO,0.0) + Value

# the output is unsorted by default, but you could sort or preserve original order
for POKey in ValueD:
    print OutD[POKey].format(ValueD[POKey])
```

P.S. Yes, I know Capitals are for Classes, but this makes it easier to tell what variables I have defined...

Comment: PERFECT! This is exactly what i was looking for. Just need to integrate it with the current script. Thanks very much for the quick and spot on reply.

Answer (score 2):

I won't give you the solution. But you should:

1. Write and test a regular expression that breaks the line down into its parts, or use the CSV library.
2. Parse the numbers out so they're decimal numbers rather than strings
3. Collect the lines up by ID. Perhaps you could use a dict that maps IDs to lists of orders?
4. When all the input is finished, iterate over that dict and add up all orders stored in that list.
5. Make a string format function that outputs the line in the expected format.
6. Maybe feed the output back into the input to test that you get the same result. Second time round there should be no changes, if I understood the problem.

Good luck!

Comment: I'm not sure using a regular expression for data which looks to me like it's in `csv` format is the right approach: that's what the `csv` module is for.

Comment: Oh yeah, didn't spot that. Or CSV if it works. That's really an implementation detail.

Comment: Just a quick thank you for the swift and helpful response. Really good community on here.